# Как в PHP кодировать строку с ISO-8859-1 в UTF-8 так, чтобы текст выводился в браузере на русском языке, а не в виде кракозябров?

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8

Я через PHP-функцию `utf8_encode` кодировал текст с ISO-8859-1 в UTF-8, получились кракозябры, а не ожидаемый результат

Например, вот этот инструмент https://www.online-decoder.com/ru кодирует нормально (из ISO-8859-1 в UTF-8)

Вопрос, как сделать так чтоб в PHP текст из ISO-8859-1 в UTF-8 кодировался так, как этот инструмент?

Comment: Давайте примеры входа и выхода.

Comment: А вообще в iso-8859-1 нет русских букв, так что видимо на самом деле у вас какая-то проблема

Comment: @AlexeyTen например: `ÐÐ±ÑÐ°Ð·ÐµÑ` (это текст в ISO-8859-1) (URI-кодированный текст (UTF-8): %C3%90%C2%9E%C3%90%C2%B1%C3%91%C2%80%C3%90%C2%B0%C3%90%C2%B7%C3%90%C2%B5%C3%91%C2%86).

Через инструмент выводится текст `Образец` (это текст в UTF-8) (так и должно быть).

А через PHP-функцию `utf8_encode` выводится текст
`ÃÂÃÂ±ÃÂÃÂ°ÃÂ·ÃÂµÃÂ` (так не должно быть)

Comment: `%C3%90%C2%9E%C3...` это UTF-8 прочитанный как ISO-8859-1 и закодированный в urlencode. Так что на самом деле вам нужен `utf8_decode` http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e8334579eb1ae02b82d231a443966419da14c20

Comment: Уже нашёл решение проблемы `iconv('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1', $text);` (до того как прочитал комментарий)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `utf8_encode($text);`, но если `utf8_encode($text);` выводит кракозябры, то используйте `iconv('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1', $text);`